# Xamarin Android - how to access Activity context from an event handler?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am running a call to a WCF service in a Xamarin.Android app like so:

```
WCF.TestCompleted += WCF_TestCompleted;
WCF.TestAsync("stringtest");
```

It has an event handler like this:

```
        public static void WCF_TestCompleted(object sender, TestCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       // various code
        ListAdapter = new OrdersAdapter(this, order, orderDetail);
    }
```

However I cannot access my list adaptor in this even handler because "this" has no context and is expecting the **Activity** context.

How can I access the main context again?

From reading over posts on StackOverlfow I thought the answe would be:

```
ListAdapter = new OrdersAdapter(Application.context, order, orderDetail);
```

But this returns an error:

**Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Android.Content.Context' to 'Android.App.Activity'**

Answer (score 0):

You could group the WCF object and a reference to the activity in a Facade like pattern class:

```
class WCFFacadeThingy()
{
    Activity myActivity;
    public WCF;
    WCFFacadeThingy(Activity activity)
    {
      myActivity = activity;

      initWCF(); //init the WCF instance in here
      WCF.TestCompleted += WCF_TestCompleted;
    }

     //Note not static method here
    public void WCF_TestCompleted(object sender, 
     TestCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       // various code
        ListAdapter list = new OrdersAdapter(myActivity, order, orderDetail);
    } 
}
```

And then somewhere in your activity:

```
WCFFacadeThingy w = new WCFFacadeThingy(this);
w.WCF.TestAsync("stringtest");
```

It might also be worth making the activity a weak reference incase it needs to be destroyed to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: Sorry I am a little confused what would the "MyActivity" property be on WCF? WCF is a web client. If I go WCF.MyActivity = this; it says that the web client WCF does not contain a definition for "MyActivity".

Comment: Modified the solution